# How to remove the red color indictors at the beginning of all the code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I updated Visual Studio Code, I am getting this annoying red indicator/highlighting before every line of code. Before the update, didn't have this issue. Does anyone know what is this and how to get rid of it?

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I tried resetting and changing the theme but it didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

I think this extension is causing your problem:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow

Try to disable/uninstall the "Indent-Rainbow" extension if it is installed.

For the "Trailing Spaces" extension, you can disable the highlighting option by adding this line to the settings.json file.

```json
{
  "trailing-spaces.highlightCurrentLine": false 
}
```

You can find more settings here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shardulm94.trailing-spaces

Answer (score 5):

I kept the Indent Rainbow extension, but added this to my settings.json to disable the red highlights:

```
    "indentRainbow.ignoreErrorLanguages": [
    "markdown",
    "python"
    ]
```

Answer (score 2):

On the bottom bar, to the right, just beside the "Ln XX and Col XX" you can choose "Select Indentation" to indent using spaces or tabs. Change that configuration or choose "detect indentation from content" and will solve the red background.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I thought it must be some extension causing this and so I took a deeper look at all my extensions.
In my case there was an extension called 'trailing spaces' which was causing this.
the red highlighting disappeared as soon as I uninstalled it.
Try doing the same and if it doesn't work try to take a look at all of your extensions. (An easier way to do that would be to go over the extensions tab on the left navigation bar in settings menu).

Comment: This was the culprit for me too. I believe the highlighting getting stuck "on" is a bug. I still like the ability to highlight or delete trailing spaces, so I edited the Extension Settings to disable "Live Matching"

Answer (score 1):

I just had to change the tab size from 4 to 2 (as configured within my eslint setup)

Comment: For me it was the editor.tabSize setting that I had to change from 4 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was an extension called Bracket Pair Colorizer

Answer (score -1):

Unistall Unneccessary Extensions

1. trailling space
2. indent-Rainbow
3. Colorized-Brackets2 (its not compitable in some systems)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).