# VSCode - Remove space/tab highlighting

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I've tried several settings found here and elsewhere to remove the highlighting shown below but have been unable to remove it.
[image]

Here's the Help About:
[image]

Comment: which one? the faded rainbow highlight? the red one before the ending curly bracket?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. There's a copy button _right there_. Also, you've only provided one of the two pieces of info I asked for.

Comment: Disabling extensions cleared the problem. Working on the rest.

Comment: Found it.  Indent Rainbow was causing the problem. Now Disabled and it's much easier to read the code. Thanks, you also taught me a few things about VSCode which I'm just starting to use so Thanks for that too!  If you'll write this up as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: please flag to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59090648/11107541